# Bathtub faucet handle stripped

Tags: plumbing

How can I fix the faucet handle when there is only metal piece left as in image? Can I use epoxy and use a universal handle? Universal handle will not stick to this.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What's stripped, exactly? I'd have expected that a set screw attaches your handle to that shaft.

Comment: use caliper and measure the diameter of that rod.  Now armed with that information go shopping for fitting handle.

Comment: That piece is not "stripped", it is a metal shaft, usually with a flat, that takes this style of faucet: https://www.amazon.com/RP63194SS-Ashton-Handle-Button-Stainless/dp/B005DMI8UE/ref=sr_1_15 , which has a setscrew to hold it onto the shaft. Of course, you'd need to find the *correct* model for that faucet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the brand and model number, and buy the parts. They usually don't sell the handle by itself, but only together with the ball base. For example: https://www.deltafaucet.com/parts/product/RP54870.html

It might seem expensive, but it beats installing a new faucet and controls.

Answer (score -1):

There is no place for a screw. I was thinking a quick fix will be put eproxy to make a grip and then use universal handle like this[image]

Comment: Those handles have clamps in them that should hold by themselves.  If not can grind/file a couple of flats on the rod.

Comment: HI Joe, please edit the question to post more information.